# How to Secure SQLite database?

Tags: windows, sqlite, encryption, electron, acl

We have a windows application which is written by electron and SQLite as database, the problem is we want our application to secure the database file after its first authentication with database, and only have the application itself can modify the file, while preventing the windows standard user from modifying or deleting the file manually. What are the options here?

Comment: There aren't any options. A local administrator can always take ownership of the SQLite database file and delete it.

Comment: sqlite is designed for local use only. there is no such thing as authentication. if your application can read/write sqlite database file, it can do anything

Comment: maybe you can crypt the file with something like that: https://github.com/OsamaAbbas/bytenode but realy save isnt it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use third-party applications like https://robotronic.de/runasspcen.html

Run application as another user or start program as administrator from a limited account like the command runas, but without to enter login information on each start.

[image: RunAsSpc]